# ObjC: Duplicate NSLog() output in the console when reading in char's with scanf()

Tags: objective-c, c, ascii, scanf

And here I thought I was getting competent at ObjC, and this little C-type problem is giving me fits.  :)  This program is intended to read in a character from user input and print an expression that gives the character's decimal value.  This program is generating duplicate NSLog() statements and I can't figure out why:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

char a;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"Type in an ASCII character or type 'command-.' to exit.");
    scanf("%c", &a);
    NSLog(@"%c = %d", a, a);
}

[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Type in an ASCII character or  type 'command-.' to exit.
a
a = 97
Type in an ASCII character or type 'command-.' to exit.
 = 10
Type in an ASCII character or type 'command-.' to exit.
```

When I change the read-in variable from a char to an int and make the according format specifier modification in the scanf(), the program runs in the console as intended.  (Prompting the user for a character, printing out the value, and prompting again.)  As soon as I go back to a char though, it does this.  What am I doing wrong?  Also, regardless of what type of char I enter, there's always the "= 10" output.  What's the deal with that?  Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: Thanks, sch.  I didn't intend to delete the " = 10".  Just accidentally deleted it when I was getting rid of the NSLog timestamps.  Thanks for picking that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"= 10"` is the ascii code for the enter key.

So change your code into:

```
scanf("\n%c", &a);
```

Comment: Wow, I suck at this.  :)  Thanks for your help.  Worked like a charm, ofc.